# Traverse a graph, one vertex, all possible round trips

Tags: graph, traversal, rounding

I have an interesting question at hand. I want to solve a problem of starting from a source vertex of a weighted graph, and find out all possible paths that lead back to it.

**For eg:** Consider a directed graph above:
[image]

---

Expected Output If I start from Source=A:

1) A -> C -> D -> B-> A

2) A -> B -> A

3) A -> D -> B -> A

**Note:**

---

a) The graph will be weighted and I'am finding the sum(not necessarily minimum sum) of the edges as I traverse.

b) Planning to represent the graph using a matrix, and **the graph may be Cyclic at some places.**

b) Which is the most efficient code that'll solve this? I know about BFS and DFS, but they dont calculate round trips!

Current DFS CODE: (adjacency graph)

```
void dfs(int cost[][20],int v[],int n, int j)
{
int i;
v[j]=1;
printf("Vistiing %d\n",j);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
if(cost[j][i]==1 && v[i]==0)
dfs(cost,v,n,i
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by modifying DFS (or BFS).

Consider DFS.

Once you visit the nodes mark it as visited. Once you return from it, mark it un-visited so that other paths can be recognized.

Your example:

```
Start from A.
Choose a path.
A->B->A.
Return to B. No other paths.
Return to A. Mark B unvisited. Choose another path.
A->D->B->A.
Return to B. No other paths.
Return to D. Mark B unvisited. No other paths.
Return to A. Mark D unvisited. Choose another path.
A->C->D->B->A.
```

Note: The important thing here is to mark the nodes un-visited.

Comment: This concept or marking/unmarking basically can be summarized as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking , but the idea is obviously feasible, so +1

Comment: How would i implement this using code? Since I'm using recursion to get across vertices, how do I know when I'm returning?

Comment: @Marco13 I know about backtracking, but I didn't want to label it straight away.

Comment: Also, since DFS traversal happens from a visited to an unvisited vertex, how will a->b->a work? When I am at B, it is marked visited. Also, A is marked visited previously( A->B) , hence (B->A) would mean selecting an edge with 2 visited nodes??

Comment: @user3210476 No, A is not marked. You want round trips at A. So A is not marked.

Comment: @user3210476 The idea is given. Play along with it and you'll find a way to write the code. It is not possible for us to write codes every time.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a nice application case for [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

- Start with the desired node
- If you reached the start node for the second time, return the result
- Otherwise: For each neighbor

  - Add the neighbor to the current path
  - Do the recursion
  - Remove the neighbor from the current path

This is implemented here as an example. Of course, this (particularly the graph data structure) is only a **quick sketch** to show that the idea is feasible, in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class GraphRoundTrips
{
    static class Vertex
    {
        String name;
        Vertex(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    static class Edge
    {
        Vertex v0;
        Vertex v1;
        Edge(Vertex v0, Vertex v1)
        {
            this.v0 = v0;
            this.v1 = v1;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "("+v0+","+v1+")";
        }
    }

    static class Graph
    {
        List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

        void addVertex(Vertex v)
        {
            vertices.add(v);
        }
        void addEdge(Edge e)
        {
            edges.add(e);
        }

        List<Vertex> getOutNeighbors(Vertex v)
        {
            List<Vertex> result = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
            for (Edge e : edges)
            {
                if (e.v0.equals(v))
                {
                    result.add(e.v1);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vertex A = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex B = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex C = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex D = new Vertex("D");

        Graph graph = new Graph();
        graph.addVertex(A);
        graph.addVertex(B);
        graph.addVertex(C);
        graph.addVertex(D);

        graph.addEdge(new Edge(A,C));
        graph.addEdge(new Edge(A,D));
        graph.addEdge(new Edge(A,B));
        graph.addEdge(new Edge(B,A));
        graph.addEdge(new Edge(C,D));
        graph.addEdge(new Edge(D,B));

        compute(graph, A, null, new LinkedHashSet<Vertex>());

    }

    private static void compute(Graph g, Vertex startVertex, 
        Vertex currentVertex, Set<Vertex> currentPath)
    {
        if (startVertex.equals(currentVertex))
        {
            List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
            path.add(startVertex);
            path.addAll(currentPath);
            System.out.println("Result "+path);
        }
        if (currentVertex == null)
        {
            currentVertex = startVertex;
        }
        List<Vertex> neighbors = g.getOutNeighbors(currentVertex);
        for (Vertex neighbor : neighbors)
        {
            if (!currentPath.contains(neighbor))
            {
                currentPath.add(neighbor);
                compute(g, startVertex, neighbor, currentPath);
                currentPath.remove(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Sorry ! But I have to implement this Using C! And so I thought of using matrices to represent the graph, as otherwise the implementation would become a nightmare ;(! Could I share my existing C code with you?

Comment: @user3210476 The basic approach is the same in any language (albeit C being faaar more inconvenient than Java - let's get the rant started :D). I only added the implementation because I just tried it out and had it available, so ... why not. If you already have started with a C implementation, you should consider adding it to your question anyhow, and explain where you are stuck or what does not work as expected.